# Shutting down services - Combining a HandlerInterceptor and ServletContextListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I'm currently working on shutting down a service gracefully, and to do so we need to check that all current requests have been completed before initiating shutdown. Here's my shutdown handler:

```
@Service
public class ShutdownHandler implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private int inflightRequests;
    public void handleShutdown() {
        if(inflightRequests == 0) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(...) throws Exception {
        inflightRequests++;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(...) {
        inflightRequests--;
    }
}
```

How can I add a call to handleShutdown() in my contextDestroyed() method of my context listener as well as adding it as a handler interceptor? Is there any way to use @Autowired?

Comment: So you want to put context shutdown on hold until the last request is handled. You could try adding a static method to ShutdownHandler that, when called, waits until all requests are complete. However, I'm not sure of the timing around when contextDestroyed is called.

Comment: @Steve11235 I understand that part, the difficulty I'm having is that I'm finding it hard to add the ShutdownHandler as both part of the contextListener as well as a HandlerInterceptor without creating two different instances of it.

Comment: ShutdownHandler doesn't need to know about the context listener. It needs to expose itself. I suggested a static method. The context listener would call the method; the method would block until all requests were done.

Comment: @Steve11235 So are you suggesting just adding it as an interceptor and having context destroyed create a new shutdown handler and calling that static method which then would work across multiple objects?

Comment: So I just make inflightRequests static then created a new ShutdownHandler to handle it using the static int. That ended up working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed InflightRequests to be static, created a new shutdown handler when servlet context was destroyed and called the shutdown method. Overall there are 2 instances of the shutdown handler, but it seems to work.